# Android Development How to Setup

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

I have the eclipse setup for Android Development 
and i need to test the android app using eclipse with old setup. 
I need to test the app for API level 28. I don't have the  SDK platform 
and system image

I get the sdk platform and system image here .
https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/AndroidSystemImages
https://androidsdkmanager.azurewebsites.net/SDKPlatform

I put all the file in the SDK folder 
I try to create  new device with API level 28 
but i cant create.

I don't know how to install new emulator compatible to the API level 28 .

I don't have experiences in eclipse environment .

My goal is to test the app using emulator with api28 
I try to connect the it using the USB  actual devices but it cant recognise by eclipse but the older phone work in the USB so I can test the app .

So my question here how to install manual the emulator with API 28 
to test the app and debug it . is there step by step how to install new API in SDK to the eclipse and install new emulator

I try the to make apk file and install in the latest android if I do this 
I can't get the error of the app so I need the emulator  to debug the android app

So my Goal here Debug my app in the eclipse with my current setup . 
debug the app with API 28 .

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to extract those downloaded files into their appropriate directories.
first look for Android SDk install location.
in my case its

```
C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
<DIR> build-tools //build-tools are extracted here
<DIR> patcher //patcher are extracted here
<DIR> platform-tools //platform-tools are extracted here
<DIR> system-images //system-images are extracted here
<DIR> platforms //platforms  are extracted here
<DIR> sources //sources  are extracted here
<DIR> tools //sdk-tools are extracted here
```

**How to create an AVD in Eclipse**

Assuming your Android Eclipse work environment is set up properly, creating a new Android Virtual Device (AVD) is simple. Just follow these steps.

1. In Eclipse, click the Window menu, then click Android SDK and AVD
   Manager.
2. On the Android SDK and AVD Manager dialog that pops up, you'll see a list of any Android AVDs you have already created:

Just click the "New..." button here to start creating a new AVD.

3) On the "Create new Android Virtual Device" dialog, just choose the options you want for your Android virtual device emulator, as shown here:

After filling out all the parameters, just click the "Create AVD" button, and your new AVD will be created, and it will appear in the list of Android Virtual Devices in the previous dialog, like this:

You can now use this AVD in your Eclipse/Android development projects.